# Trigonometric Simplification and Double Angle Formula

Tags: simplifying-expressions, linear-algebra, trigonometry

I am trying to achieve the formula `hbar / 2 * cos(wt) * sin(theta)`. However, my Mathematica expression doesn't seem to simplify the half/double angle formulas. I am wondering how I could refine my approach. Here's my code:

```
Sz[J_] := ℏ*
  Table[ KroneckerDelta[i, j]*(J + 1 - i), {i, 2*J + 1}, {j, 2*J + 1}]
Sx[J_] := Chop[ℏ*.5*
   Table[(KroneckerDelta[i, j + 1] + 
       KroneckerDelta[i + 1, j])*((J + 1)*(i + j - 1) - i*j)^.5, {i, 
     2*J + 1}, {j, 2*J + 1}]]
Sy[J_] := ℏ*
  Table[I/2*(KroneckerDelta[i, j + 1] - 
      KroneckerDelta[i + 1, j])*((J + 1)*(i + j - 1) - i*j)^.5, {i, 
    2*J + 1}, {j, 2*J + 1}]
Sn[J_, theta_, phi_] := 
 Simplify[Sx[J]*Sin[theta]*Cos[phi] + Sy[J]*Sin[theta]*Sin[phi] + 
   Sz[J]*Cos[theta], 
  Assumptions -> {0 <= theta <= Pi, 0 <= phi < 2*Pi, 
    Element[theta, Reals]}]
U[H_, t_] := 
 Simplify[Chop[ComplexExpand[MatrixExp[-I*H*t/ℏ]]], 
  Assumptions -> Element[t, Reals]]

{nvals, nvecs} = Eigensystem[Sn[.5, theta, 0]];
psi = Simplify[U[w Sz[.5], t].nvecs[[2]], 
   Assumptions -> Element[w, Reals]];
Simplify[ComplexExpand[Conjugate[psi].Sx[.5].psi]]
```

And here's my output:

```
(ℏ Sin[
  theta] ((-2. - 2. Cos[theta]) Cos[(0.5 + 0. I) t w]^2 + (2. + 
      2. Cos[theta]) Sin[(0.5 + 0. I) t w]^2))/(-1. + Cos[2 theta])
```

Comment: Your expression simplifies to `\[HBar] Cos[t w] Cot[theta/2]`, which I found by applying `TrigExpand` and then `Simplify`. Combinations of `Simplify`, `TrigExpand`, and `TrigReduce` often work for these kinds of simpifications.

Comment: If you change `.5` to `(1/2)` throughout your code, you will get `\[HBar] Cos[t w] Cot[theta/2]`. With exact numbers, you also do not need to use `Chop`.